# How to set download directory on Chrome with Ubuntu on Selenium

Tags: python, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

With Selenium on my Ubuntu EC2 instance, I'm trying to set the download directory of Chrome to `/home/ubuntu/resolucion`, but the files downloaded are going to `/home/ubuntu` (where my script `main.py` is). I tried not using `os` and just typing `"download.default_directory": "/home/ubuntu/resolucion"` but still not working. The code below only works fine on my pc.

Note: there are no errors on the browser logs, neither any kind of error during script execution.

main.py

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import os

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--headless")

dir_base = os.path.abspath(os.curdir)
carpeta_resolucion = os.path.join(dir_base, "resolucion")

options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
    "download.default_directory": carpeta_resolucion,
    "browser.downloads.dir": carpeta_resolucion,
    "directory_upgrade": True,
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "download.extensions_to_open": "application/xml",
    "safebrowsing.enabled": True
})

print(options.to_capabilities())

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(
    ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
```

This is the printed information of `options.to_capabilities()`:

```
{'browserName': 'chrome', 'pageLoadStrategy': 'normal', 'goog:chromeOptions': {'prefs': {'download.default_directory': '/home/ubuntu/resolucion', 'browser.downloads.dir': '/home/ubuntu/resolucion', 'directory_upgrade': True, 'download.prompt_for_download': False, 'download.extensions_to_open': 'application/xml', 'safebrowsing.enabled': True}, 'extensions': [], 'args': ['--no-sandbox', '--headless']}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the download location using `--user-data-dir` and `download.default_directory` instead of `options.add_experimental_option`

remove all the `options.add_experimental_option` code and instead add

```
options.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir={dir_base}/user-data")
options.add_argument(f"--download.default_directory={carpeta_resolucion}")
```

This might fix your problem and allow you to set the Download directory on your EC2

Answer (score 0):

I see a few possible issues with this, firstly: are you sure that it is getting the path correctly?

You may want to change these two lines to the full path directory (From your print, it looks like maybe `'/home/ubuntu/resolucion'`) instead of a relative one. (Most IDEs will let you right click the path and copy it directly. Make sure that this directory actually exists and isn't just a symbolic link to a non-existent directory. You can always add a check and use `os.mkdir()` if this is what breaks it.

```py
dir_base = os.path.abspath(os.curdir)
carpeta_resolucion = os.path.join(dir_base, "resolucion")
```

An easier way to do this altogether, though, is to just use `--user-data-dir` and `download.default_directory` instead.

(Edit: just saw the other answer also mentioned this!)

If both of those didnt work, the issue could be with your Linux permission group. If for example `Ubuntu` is the user, you could do something like `sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /home/ubuntu/resolucion`